# How to tell if multiple sites contain a keyword

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, search, query, screen-scraping

I have a list of 9k web addresses, and a couple of keywords.

I would like to know if a webpage contains that word. Ideally, automated google search with some search operators would work great, for example if you would search

```
"keyword" site:"https://www.example.com"
```

result would be satisfactory (as it will return *"not found"* or a bunch of url's where keyword was found), but as  I have so mane webpages, it is against their terms and conditions to automate search through all 9k webpages.

What would be a conventional way to do this?

I am not asking for a way to trick google, just for any other possibilities which are not google related at all I could lookup.

Comment: If automated searching is against their terms and conditions, then why are you asking for a way to do just that?

Comment: It is against googles terms and conditions. If I am implying to provide me a way to play google, that was not what I meant. Maybe there are some other ways to achieve this, which is what I am asking for.